# Trouble with assertEquals

Tags: java, testcase

Ok I am tasked with making a test class for a class Fraction that includes addition, subtraction, division, and multiplication. I started with the testAdd method first, but seems no matter how I try to approach testing it, it always fails. An example would be that i put the expected answer in assertEquals("10/8",f2.add(f1)); and it would say that it fails with the warning sign stating expected <10/8> but actual was <10/8>. I would even use another fraction instance variable to supplement the answer by typing assertEquals(f3,f2.add(f1)); and still give me the same reply.

Here is the Fraction class(fraction class was already provided):

```
    // import ArithmeticException class for use in division method
import java.lang.ArithmeticException;



public class Fraction
{

        /**
         *  Instance Variables
         **/
 private int numerator;          // Stores the numerator of the fraction
 private int denominator;        // Stores the denominator of the fraction



        /**
         * Constructor
         * Takes two integer arguments, the numerator and denominator for the fraction
         * being created.
         **/
 public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator)
 {
                // initialize instance variables
  this.numerator = numerator;
  this.denominator = denominator;
 }
        // end constructor



        /**
         * Additon Method
         * Takes one Fraction argument, calculates the sum of the
         * calling Fraction object and its argument, constructs a new Fraction
         * object that stores the sum, and returns this new Fraction object.
         **/
 public Fraction add( Fraction otherFraction )
 {

                // declare and initialize local variables for the numerator and denominator
  int commonDenominator  = this.denominator * otherFraction.denominator;
  int newNumerator = ( this.numerator * otherFraction.denominator ) + ( otherFraction.numerator * this.denominator );

                // Declare and initialize resulting Fraction object using the above numerator and denominator
  Fraction result = new Fraction( newNumerator, commonDenominator );

  return result;

 }
        // end add method



        /**
         * Subtraction  Method
         * Takes one Fraction argument, calculates the difference of the
         * calling Fraction object and its argument, constructs a new Fraction
         * object that stores the difference, and returns this new Fraction object.
         **/
 public Fraction subtract( Fraction otherFraction )
 {

                // declare and initialize local variables for the numerator and denominator
  int commonDenominator = this.denominator * otherFraction.denominator;
  int newNumerator = ( this.numerator * otherFraction.denominator ) - ( otherFraction.numerator * this.denominator );

                // Declare and initialize resulting Fraction object using the above numerator and denominator
  Fraction result = new Fraction( newNumerator, commonDenominator );

  return result;

 }
        // end subtract method



        /**
         * Multiplication Method
         * Takes one Fraction argument, calculates the multiple of the
         * calling Fraction object and its argument, constructs a new Fraction
         * object that stores the multiple, and returns this new Fraction object.
         **/
 public Fraction multiply( Fraction otherFraction )
 {

                // declare and initialize local variables for the numerator and denominator
                int newNumerator = this.numerator * otherFraction.numerator;
                int newDenominator = this.denominator * otherFraction.denominator;

                // Declare and initialize resulting Fraction object using the above numerator and denominator
                Fraction result = new Fraction( newNumerator, newDenominator );

  return result;

 }
        // end multiply method



        /**
         * Division Method
         * Takes one Fraction argument, calculates the dividend of the
         * calling Fraction object and its argument, constructs a new Fraction
         * object that stores the dividend, and returns this new Fraction object.
         **/
 public Fraction divide( Fraction otherFraction ) throws ArithmeticException
 {

                // If the nominator of the divisor is zero throw a division by zero exception
                if( otherFraction.numerator == 0 )
                {

                    throw new ArithmeticException( "Division by Zero" );

                }

                // Construct a new Fraction object that is the inverse of the divisor
  Fraction inverse = new Fraction( otherFraction.denominator, otherFraction.numerator );

                // Calculate the result of the division by multiplying by the inverse of the divisor
                // and store the result in a new Fraction object.
  Fraction result = this.multiply( inverse);

  return result;

 }
        // end divide method



        /**
         * String Conversion Method
         * Uses the state of the object (the numerator and denominator), converts
         * them to strings and the returns a String representation of the Fraction
         * object.
         **/
 public String toString()
 {
  String text = Integer.toString(this.numerator) + "/" + Integer.toString(this.denominator);

  return text;
 }
        // end toString method

}
// END CLASS FRACTION
```

I also have the package in the class so that is not the problem.
Here is the testclass I have tried to create:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;


public class TestFraction extends TestCase{

  Fraction f1;
  Fraction f2;
  Fraction f3;
  Fraction f4;
  Fraction result1;
  Fraction result2;
  Fraction result3;
  Fraction result4;

  protected void setUp(){

    f1 = new Fraction(1,2);
    f2 = new Fraction(3,4);
    f3 = new Fraction(10,8);
    f4 = new Fraction(2,3);

  }

  public void testAdd(){
    assertEquals(,f2.add(f1));
  }

  public void testSubtract(){

  }

  public void testDivide(){

  }

  public void testMultiply(){

  }



}
```

Comment: looks to me I have a lot of researching to do. Thank you all for your assistance in this assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `equals()`, you're relying on `Object.equals()` for testing equality.  This will return true only if two Fractions are the same object.  You want them to be equal if they represent the same value.

When writing `equals()`, you have to write `hashCode()` too, according to the contract of those methods.

And when writing `equals()`, don't forget that `new Fraction(5, 4).equals(new Fraction(20, 16)) == true`.

Comment: Thank you for the help I am trying out both user276451 and yours to make sure I have all my bases covered

Comment: They're the same suggestion :)  I just added the "why" to the "what".

Answer (score 1):

After implementing `equals()` and `hashcode()` for class `Fraction`, do `assertEquals(new Fraction(10,8), f2.add(f1));`

Or if you're not sure about `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods, just hack out
`assertEquals("10/8", f2.add(f1).toString());`

The `add` method returns `Fraction` but when you write `assertEquals("10/8", f2.add(f1))`, the `"10/8"` is of `String` type but `f2.add(f1)` is returning `Fraction` so since there's a type mismatch, test fails.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. and the same goes if I were to do f2.divide(f1) and so on and so forth?

Comment: none of the 2 suggestions I've given require the said constructor

Comment: @user3255993 if you implement `equals()` and `hashcode()`, you wouldn't have to write `f2.divide(f1).toString()` and `f2.multiply(f1).toString()` and so on (basically you wouldn't have to write `toString()` everywhere. but if you don't implement the two said methods, you'd have to do that - which is ideally, a bad way.

Comment: Ah sorry.. I misread something, I guess.  I thought I read a Fraction constructor with a string parameter

Comment: Yes, adding equals() will make assertEquals() work for all those tests.  BTW, consider switching to JUnit4-style annotated tests, they're more readable and don't require extending a base class.  And consider reading up on Hamcrest and Fest, which make assertions more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) methods for your Fraction class.

For instance, your `equals()` method would look something like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (!(other instanceof Fraction)) {
        return false;
    }
    otherFraction = (Fraction) other;
    return numerator * otherFraction.denominator == otherFraction.numerator * denominator;
```

While your `hashCode()` method would look something like this:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return new Double((double) numerator / denominator).hashCode();
}
```

Comment: Do you really want a floating-point calculation in your hashCode()?  Hopefully there's a solution that avoids that.

Comment: @PaulHicks I can't think of an obvious one besides just reducing the fraction in the first place.

Comment: Reducing the fraction is a reasonable way to go.  A static method for this has a high chance of being reused, too.  hashCode() is rarely used, especially in homework projects like this, so performance considerations can be postponed until required (read: indefinitely).